# Error creating new Ruby on Rails 3.0 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I' trying to make my first steps with Ruby on Rails. I'm working on a Ubuntu 14.04. As suggested by a website, I've installed rvm to manage my Ruby installations and gem sets. 
The commands I've used are

```
rvm install ruby-1.9.2-p320
rvm use --default 1.9.2-p320
gem install rails -v 3.0
```

At the moment, this is the situation with the installation

```
<01/nov 15:25> [Ruby_On_Rails]$ rvm list
rvm rubies

=* ruby-1.9.2-p320 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-1.9.3-p547 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-2.1.2 [ x86_64 ]
ruby-head [ x86_64 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

and here is the gemset list

```
<01/nov 15:28> [Ruby_On_Rails]$ rvm gemset list

gemsets for ruby-1.9.2-p320 (found in /home/lorenzo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320)
=> (default)
global
```

finally, here is the gem list

```
<01/nov 15:30> [Ruby_On_Rails]$ gem list

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

abstract (1.0.0)
actionmailer (3.0.0)
actionpack (3.0.0)
activemodel (3.0.0)
activerecord (3.0.0)
activeresource (3.0.0)
activesupport (3.0.0)
arel (1.0.1)
builder (2.1.2)
bundler (1.7.4, 1.0.22)
bundler-unload (1.0.2)
erubis (2.6.6)
executable-hooks (1.3.2)
gem-wrappers (1.2.7)
i18n (0.7.0.beta1, 0.4.2)
json (1.8.1)
mail (2.2.20)
mime-types (1.25.1)
minitest (5.4.2, 1.6.0)
polyglot (0.3.5)
rack (1.2.8)
rack-mount (0.6.14)
rack-test (0.5.7)
rails (3.0.0)
railties (3.0.0)
rake (0.8.7)
rdoc (2.5.8)
rubygems-bundler (1.4.4)
rvm (1.11.3.9)
thor (0.14.6)
thread_safe (0.3.4)
treetop (1.4.15)
tzinfo (1.2.2, 0.3.42)
```

When I try to launch rails new, it gives me an error becuse one of the ruby gems is in conflict with rails 3.0

```
<01/nov 15:22> [Ruby_On_Rails]$ rails --version
/home/lorenzo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:2064:in `raise_if_conflicts': Unable to activate rails-3.0.0, because bundler-1.7.4 conflicts with bundler (~> 1.0.0) (Gem::LoadError)
    from /home/lorenzo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/specification.rb:1262:in `activate'
    from /home/lorenzo/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p320/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_gem.rb:54:in `gem'
    from /home/lorenzo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/rails:22:in `<main>'
    from /home/lorenzo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `eval'
    from /home/lorenzo/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p320/bin/ruby_executable_hooks:15:in `<main>'
```

In fact, I have two versions of bundler. I'm not an expert, but I think that "bundler (~> 1.0.0)" means bundler 1.0.x, so it gives me problem because the version is "too new" for rails. Now I'd like to understant the "correct" action to perform to make a coherent situation. Should I uninstall bundler 1.7.2? Are ruby 1.9.2 and rails 3.0 incompatible?

The main problem is that I'm new with Ruby, so maybe there is something obiouvs that I've not seen in the outputs of the commands. I've tried to google a bit, but I've found anything, so any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Rails 3.0 is very old. Is there any reason you're not using a modern version of Rails, like Rails 4.1? If not, learn Rails 4.1. Much of the specifics you learn in Rails 3.0 have gone away or changed significantly, so you're learning stuff that isn't actually useful in new applications. There are some very *large* and extremely important parts of Rails you're missing like the entire asset pipeline.

Comment: Good question :)
I've just found a rails 3.0 book. I think it's good enough to unserstand the basics of the framework... and moreover it was a good way to understand a bit better how rvm works (i.e. create a separate installation, gemset, etc etc)

Comment: It's really not a good idea. At least learn Rails 3.2, which is the most recent 3.x version. Rails 3.0 is pretty much dead, and lacks some *major* functionality that is now *extremely* core to developing Rails applications.

Comment: does rails 3.2 still work with ruby 1.9.2?

Comment: Rails 3.2 will work with Ruby 1.8.7 or newer, but you should at least be on Ruby 1.9.

Comment: Ok, I've found some tutorial for rails 4.x, so I'm moving to that version :)
thanks a lot!

Comment: Be aware that Ruby 1.9.2 is end-of-life since [July '14](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2014/07/01/eol-for-1-8-7-and-1-9-2/). I'd strongly recommend to switch over to Ruby 2.1.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
gem uninstall bundler
gem install bundler --version '1.0.0'
```

then:

```
bundle
```

*P.S*

*I totally agree with @meagar, unless you are forced to with legacy code you should move forward to a more recent version of rails ... you will miss lots of fun!*

Comment: It worked, I just directly tried `gem install rails` instead of installing bundler alone.